# Implementation of different BCrypt versions

Tags: php, android, ios, bcrypt

I'm fairly new to encryption, and I am investigating the different kind of encryptions. I want to encrypt passwords in a secure way. I discussed this with my colleague, and he said that BCrypt is the best encryption for our project. We have a PHP server, Android client, and iOS client as our setup.

I am using a jBCrypt implementation for Android, and an Objective-C port of jBCrypt for iOS. My colleague is making the PHP server and he is using crypt_blowfish. He found out that the PHP implementation of $2a$ is insecure, and asked if I could use $2y$.

But I cannot find any $2y$ implementations of jBCrypt. Are these different versions compatible with each other? Is it secure to use $2a$? If it is not, is it hard to make a $2y$ version myself?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot assume that $2a$ is either secure or insecure. You need to test the implementation.

Comment: See https://www.engineyard.com/blog/password-security-part-3 for some explanations of these hash prefixes. The correct value should indeed be `$2y$`